# WordPress Media Manager

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to include an images folder that is then accessible via the admin section. I am creating a theme and want some background images available for the user, since I can not include them in the uploads folder is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Include your backgrounds into the images folder of your theme.

Create an options page that lets the user select a background and return the URL of the image.

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/backgrounds/BACKGROUNDFILENAME.jpg'; ?>
```

Comment: The options page and url bit is the easy bit. Say I have a button that allow users to select an image how will they be able to find the theme images folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to in your functions.php create or register new "Attatchment" based posts using the URLS of your theme images or try using this...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/